# Can we Update a Model Automatically Once the Database is Updated in ASP.Net MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

For Eg.

I have a table with 4 Columns

- Id
- P Id
- Name
- Gender

And a Model Named Employee with same fields

Now If I make any change in table structure
For Eg. Added Birth date Column

Is there any way, the model will be updated automatically by reading the table?

Or is there any way that i defined the table name, the columns will be fetched in Model Itself.

Answer (score 0):

You should map your model with your table using ORMs like entity framework. In your demand, if you use a database-first approach, then whenever you change your table, you can update your model by the wizard. For more information [click here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/modeling/designer/workflows/database-first)